# ForkJoinWorkerThread: should onTermination(Throwable) handle the exception or pass it to UncaughtExceptionHandler?

Tags: java, concurrency, forkjoinpool

I am extending a ForkJoinWorkerThread class. It allows to override the  onTermination(Throwable) method where one can handle the exception which forced the thread to terminate. However, there is a Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler designed for this purpose. ForkJoinPool allows you to use both. Is there any difference which way exception are handled?

It seems that handling the exception in onTermination is less complicated than implementing a new handler for this.

Answer (score 0):

You should **not** use `onTermination(Throwable)` to handle exceptions.

The [JavaDoc](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Eiris/se/15/latestSpec/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinWorkerThread.html#onTermination(java.lang.Throwable)) states:

> Performs cleanup associated with termination of this worker thread. If you override this method, you must invoke super.onTermination at the end of the overridden method.

And notes for the exception parameter:

> `exception` - the exception causing this thread to abort due to an unrecoverable error, or **null if completed normally**

So this method is called whenever the thread terminates - whether normally or exceptionally.

---

Also your wording seems strange:

> I am implementing a ForkJoinWorkerThread interface.

`ForkJoinWorkerThread` is a concrete class, not an interface. You cannot "implement the interface", you can only "extend the class".

Comment: Yeah, this is a mistake regarding interface. But still having an anonymous class extending ForkJoinWorkerThread is it a bad practice to include block if(exception != null) { ... } to the onTermination method?

Comment: @spectralm as the documentation says: it is intended for cleanup actions. Exception handling is typically **not** a cleanup action. Besides that it is unclear what exceptions you want to handle - all exceptions that occur within your tasks are caught and don't lead to the termination of the ForkJoinWorkerThread. I only ever succeeded in terminating a ForkJoinWorkerThread by shuting down the ForkJoinPool.